# How to enable user to re-entry(or) reuse the same dialog in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I'm currently doing a FTP download using MFC. Is a very simple program which takes 2 inputs from user and click a download button in order to download from server. Everything is fine and im able to download it from. But i realized this program can only be executed once. Either successful or fail user has to open the .exe again to download another file. I'm a beginner in C&C++ with a simple knowledge i put OnInitDialog() at the last line of the download function hopping it will loop back and initialize again. Of course it doesn't work. Below are my current codes for the download button

```
BOOL CFTPDOWNLOADDlg::Log_In(char* path, char* ID, char* password {       
    m_pFtpConnection = NULL;

    try{
        // path         
        // ID
        // password
        m_pFtpConnection = m_Session.GetFtpConnection(path,
        ID,password,INTERNET_INVALID_PORT_NUMBER);

    }
    catch(CInternetException *pEx){
        pEx->ReportError(MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        m_pFtpConnection = NULL;
        pEx->Delete();
        return FALSE;
    }


    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CFTPDOWNLOADDlg::Download(){

    m_Edit3.SetWindowText("Downloading..");
    m_Session.EnableStatusCallback(TRUE);

    if(m_pFtpConnection->GetFile(serv_Loc,host_Loc,
    FALSE,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY,1) != 0){
    MessageBox("Download Complete");
    m_Edit3.SetWindowText("");}
    else{
        MessageBox("Download Fail");
        return FALSE;
    }
    // Log_out Session
    m_Session.Close();
    m_pFtpConnection->Close();
    if(m_pFtpConnection!=NULL) delete m_pFtpConnection;
    else MessageBox("Download Complete");


    return TRUE;
}
BOOL CFTPDOWNLOADDlg::get_Path(){
...
...
...
    sprintf(serv_Loc,"soft\\%s\\%d\\%s.zip",s_No,r_Number,r_No);
    sprintf(host_Loc,"%s\\%s.zip",buff2,r_No);

    return TRUE;
}

void CFTPDOWNLOADDlg::OnCancel() {

    // Log_out Session
    m_Session.Close();
    m_pFtpConnection->Close();
    if(m_pFtpConnection!=NULL)
    delete m_pFtpConnection;

    CDialog::OnCancel();

}



void CFTPDOWNLOADDlg::OnDLButton() {

    //get path from user input
    get_Path();

    // start download
    Download();
}
```

I've tried to search online, i couldn't find anything which is close. Sorry for my poor explanation.

Thank you in advance for your kindness in replying

Comment: Show your full code. I believe the problem is that your FTP session is initialized and destroyed improperly.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin alright ..

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin O man... after hearing what you said i've been drilling at a wrong problem. Now i realized the error came out during second time of calling download was at the m_Session.EnableStatusCallback(TRUE), but i've close the session after download

Comment: Please do us and yourself a favor and format your program properly.

Comment: I got it done after i remove m.Session.close and m_Session.EnableStatusCallback(TRUE); I know this is not the right way. But i really don't know why......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

1. You should make `CInternetSession m_Session;` a member of your `CWinApp`-derived class.
2. You should call `m_Session.Close()` in `ExitInstance()` method of your `CWinApp`-derived class.
3. In your `CDialog`-derived class you should only deal with `CFtpConnection` related stuff. So when user clicks on **Download** button you should call `GetFtpConnection()` and initialize your `m_pFtpConnection` and do the rest. When download/upload is done call `m_pFtpConnection->Close();` and `delete m_pFtpConnection;`
4. Please also use `CString` instead of `char*`. There are lots of benefits like automatic UNICODE support, etc.
5. Please also consider using `CString::Format()` method instead of `sprintf()`.

You should also consider using threads to perform upload/download tasks in a separate worker thread. Use `AfxBeginThread()` to start the thread. This way you'll not affect Windows message pump that is a part of main application (GUI) thread. So your GUI wont lock up while you uploading/downloading files.

Comment: Thanks ! Now my title doesn't match the problem ive faced.